# Pro training input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-recognition

So I'm new to tensorflow and deep learning. I learned how to install tf and run a mnist python on tensorflow. I can also check the program training result on tensorboard.
I have 2 questions after this:
After I have trained this program, how I can use it in future ? I want to know how to give some image data to my program and it decide whether which number is it. 
And does it need to be trained each time I run the program or for future use I just give it some input data(handwritten image) and it give me result.

Based on my newbie above question please also tell me; What am I missing? What is my lack?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check out [TensorFlow serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/). First [train and evaluate the model](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners). Once you're happy with it, [export it in SavedModel format](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic). The SavedModel includes the model itself and the trained variables; just load it and start classifying images.

Comment: wow, I just needed this answer, why I've got so many down vote!

Comment: Your question is [a bit too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (specifically 4.). I wouldn't take it personally.